# jQuery maphilight not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, maphilight

What am I missing? I am using the [David Lynch](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html) maphilight plug in and have been comparing my code to this page to troubleshoot, yet after two days, I am still having an issue.  The colors won't show when I hover over (or even click) on any part of the mapped image.  The links work as expected.

My script call is:

```
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
        $('.AMGCmap1').maphilight();
    </script>
   </head>
```

and the img and map code are:

```
            <div>
                <img class ="map" id ="AMGCmap1" src="Images\AMGC Logo Big.png" alt="AMGC Logo" usemap="#AGMCmap" border="15">

                <map name="AGMCmap">
                    <area shape="poly" coords="61,432, 58,346, 71,285, 148,287, 164,345, 166,432" href="news.html"  title= "News" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.6}' >
                </map>

            </div>
```

I tried using the img ID and just "'.map'" in the function, but I am seeing no difference.  Anyone else having issues like this?

I am working in Chrome at the moment, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class ="map" id ="AMGCmap1" ...>
```

Here you have an id meanwhile you are calling a class in your script.

```
$('.AMGCmap1').maphilight();
```

That might be the problem. 
Edit either the id in your HTML to be a class:

```
<img class ="map AMGCmap1" ...>
```

or call an id in your script:

```
$('#AMGCmap1').maphilight();
```

Anyway, I also have the same problem even if I have checked my script so carefully, let me know if you could get it to work after this fix.